# angular ng-if json array contains boolean

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Angular 1 app.
Basically, there is an array of JSON object like this:

```
ctrl.messages = 
[
    {id: 1, text: 'hello1',createdBy:{name: 'Jack', hasBeenRead: false} }
    ,{id: 2, text: 'hello2',createdBy:{name: 'Steven', hasBeenRead: true} }
];
```

Now, in the view I print the messages like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    Message: {{message.text}}
</div>
```

Somewhere else I have this html:

```
<div ng-if="messages.length > 0">
<button ng-if="?">Mark all read</button>
<button ng-if="?">Mark all unread</button>
</div>
```

The buttons above will never be showing together. But only one of them (and only if there are messages at all).

I wonder if it possibile to add in the ng-if above (in the button) a code for understanding if the button has to be showing.
The button `Mark all read` will be showing only if there is at least one message marked with `hasBeenRead: false`.
The button `Mark all unread` will be showing only if all the messages have been read.

I could do this in the controller. But I thought it would be neater if I could add this directly in the view.
The difficulty for me is to access the `hasBeenRead` in the JSON from the view without iterating. Just asking "is there at least one unread message?".

Is there a way to do it in this way?

Comment: No, there isn't. Your options is either to create a `filter` or create some flag in your controller on which the statement `ng-if` should point to. I would go with the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Create filter as below

```
app.filter('hasBeenRead', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.some(val => !val.createdBy.hasBeenRead);
    }
});


<div ng-if="messages.length > 0">
    <button ng-if="!messages|hasBeenRead">Mark all read</button>
    <button ng-if="messages|hasBeenRead">Mark all unread</button>
</div>
```